# Enabling YJIT on a Rails project (is rust required?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jit

I want to enable [YJIT](https://shopify.engineering/ruby-yjit-is-production-ready) on a Rails project. I have moved the codebase to Ruby 3.2 and am trying to enable YJIT by setting the `RUBY_YJIT_ENABLE` to `1` in a canary release receiving 50% of the traffic so that I can see the two side by side.
In the canary release, with the env var set, when I SSH into production I get:

```
~/app $ env | grep YJIT
RUBY_YJIT_ENABLE=1
~/app $ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) +YJIT [x86_64-linux-musl]
```

Unfortunately, I don't see the performance benefits that [others are reporting](https://blog.discourse.org/2023/05/running-ruby-3-2s-yjit-in-production-at-discourse/). Below you can see two graphs, one for the memory usage and one the average request time for requests. In both graphs, blue is the canary release with YJIT enabled and yellow is the one with YJIT disabled (both are ruby 3.2).

[image]

[image]

That's why I wanted to ask if there is anything else that I need to do. Does the `ruby -v` output mean that YJIT is enabled?

Is the `rustc` a runtime dependency for YJIT to work? Because my current setup doesn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

It's my understanding that the `+YJIT` indicates that YJIT is enabled. I could not find any official documentation to reference but it looks like `rustc` is a compile time dependency for Ruby 3.2 but not a runtime dependency. I use the docker image `ruby:3.2.2-alpine3.18` which is only 33MB because it compiles Ruby using C and YJIT using Rust. Then it only copies over the Ruby binaries and dependencies which includes YJIT. You can verify that YJIT is actually running with the following commands.

```
docker run -it ruby:3.2.2-alpine3.18 /bin/sh
RUBYOPT=--yjit irb
RubyVM::YJIT.enabled?
=> true
RubyVM::YJIT.runtime_stats
=>
{:inline_code_size=>337228,
 :outlined_code_size=>337004,
 :freed_page_count=>0,
 :freed_code_size=>0,
 :live_page_count=>42,
 :code_gc_count=>0,
 :code_region_size=>684032,
 :object_shape_count=>706}
```

Also, looking at your graphs (although they are missing the legend so I'm assuming the light blue is the canary using YJIT), the RAM usage is higher which is the expected tradeoff (RAM vs CPU) and while not always faster the response time looks like it's often a little faster.